# including header file for size_t returned by sizeof operator

Tags: c++, sizeof, size-t

Should I include header file with definition of size_t (e.g. cstddef or stddef.h) for using sizeof keyword, which returns that type?

For example:

```
//..no include

int main()
{
    size_t n;  //error: unknown type size_t
    sizeof(int);  //ok, but returned size_t type also undefined
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to explicitly use `size_t` then yes.  If not, then no.

Comment: You have to. Poorly, I do not know which header. Also it is std::size_t for c++.

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t it is defined in multiple headers.

Comment: This is no bad question - why the down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to include `cstddef` or `stddef.h` if you need to explicitly use `size_t` (i.e. in a declaration or definition). It is not necessary if if all you want to do it determine the size of a specific type using `sizeof`. For example the following statements do not require that you include any header file to use `sizeof` in determine the size of a type.

```
int a = sizeof(foo);
if(sizeof(foo) == 12) {}
```

If you're looking specifically for information about `sizeof` I suggest you take a look at 5.3.3 (`[expr.sizeof]`) of the C++ Standard for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you don't want to include a header, you can let C++ infer the correct type:

```
decltype(sizeof(0)) n;
```

Comment: A nice one - no header at all - but ugly, too

Comment: You could write `using size_t = decltype(sizeof(0));` once, then use `size_t` as normal.